# Sync Users between different Keycloak instances

Tags: kubernetes, active-directory, ldap, keycloak, openid-connect

I work for a multi company group.
Each company has its own Network its own IT Admins and therfore its own Active-Directory.
There is no possibility to connect the different Networks via VPN for e.g.
The users of the companies can be identified from their email domain for e.g. jdoe@company-a.com and jdoe@company-b.com

My goal is to develop a global application for the whole company group.

I want to use Keycloak as Identity and Access Management.

The problem is that every user, which is member of defined groups, from all companies must have access / login / authorized to the centralized frontend and the decentralized backend (self programmed API proxy/gateway).

Here is a drawing of the current situation:

[Draw.io Feel free to edit](https://app.diagrams.net/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7V1bc6O4Ev41fjSFxM085jKZk7MzNanNmdqZeZkiQGxOMPICTuz99SvZgNHFoDhcnWS3akAIAerury9qtSfa1XLzOXZWi6%2FI88MJVL3NRLueQAhnJsT%2FkJbtvgUYqrFvmceBl7UdGu6Df%2FysUc1a14HnJ1THFKEwDVZ0o4uiyHdTqs2JY%2FRCd3tEIf3UlTPPnqgeGu5dJ%2FS5bn8FXrrYt86gdWj%2Fjx%2FMF%2FmTgWnvryydvHM2cLJwPPRSatI%2BTbSrGKF0f7TcXPkhmb18Xvb33Ry5WrxY7EepzA3ob%2FUxupzNHgD6%2Bfjj6i%2FL%2Fu9mmpHn2QnX2QdPoBni8S4f8MGcHFyh5cqJtrjXRX4NP6S4nH1cus1nLEbryPPJQwG%2B%2FLIIUv9%2B5bjk6gtmEty2SJdhdvnZj9MAz%2FZFGMwj3JYi0uERRWnGCsAk50EYXqEQxbghQhFuv%2FScZFE8JElj9OTnPSZQg8aFCq%2BLKznldNyy8uNg6ad%2BTF4qiOa4WcXNTuxmT9SLjyrPbTbd5H39Takpm%2BvPPsKDxmSWsqtTI2fhjPWnwMwaXkqMlHdalJjI1LNGJ2PeeTH6gb74ICOxmNyXN7e3ge3%2B%2FqU9frv9pad%2FXl1upvpryH35QW55ctu2BLWtmYDaOmyA2gvnx3oVbH862%2BX3p89%2Ffr%2F67c2m0ObIfY3cJz%2BekEfir1b%2FWD%2F4cYSnJ8EnV%2BE6ScnFt1CYpgAUUNfJaO%2FiycZPO4HcpnkJb26OslMTwqtBlpwqT07DFJCzaGycnJrFkcb3sLLKTrOpO1CL8DmK0wWao8gJvyAyObsJ%2Fb%2BfptuMJM46RTQF%2FU2Q%2FshuJ8c%2FybFiZGfXm9Kl621%2BEuEP%2FJEPQE5Kd5HTw227s%2Fy%2BJHXi9IKo6cMH7NpuAjI32R0e0wO3lK6z%2FHWU%2FAlax65fNcGZaYJfYO6nVR2zEcn0V7JT7IdOGjzTtkTzjDEbAWMoqmrRzKHbZg177M7ucgQfDc8ILS2rL5YRvk2OiAfNcEvQGKsCnpXCEBvbu1leOCvS6IZo7dWrAk6tk%2FNsXIH1%2BmqQNlQaozUeoQsYLyM0sBpAaOGsmtysXlxz81nM4jYMsEDG9RP5sJfcLw9Fg%2BM%2BzXfy%2FG2d4lH8rJ3W1JzeVHd%2FYiXN62BpGXmFWtVZK0lgJImU6qwtiuXmt9DcGYECZYnUBDhKgWEVxtVioT0oLLQ4qf3D32KMc55qeEPKFH69%2FOGej7u%2FloQQMLg5NXghBCLgbMKyFVJgxlGA10IHpnVDJ0kCt1rZ5EIIThFC9XVCeLrAmA0bD2XnROSbZG3ScpU94Q4F%2BMtKHGQbFAcBjeGM%2FYdnt5VjUtxIOj0SC%2FT7meEG2nFZ8d1vgH%2Be875cX9xx3IdFK6X5jfNiWV90GXheuLO7%2FST4x3nYDUW4ZUU%2BZvd5xuXEIFEL%2FH%2FoPPjhZaHWZaAgRikmIoqOMmGlqLFwUURQszedlIOUIhhRFTjL%2FaAtNdCbuctgfW9bUak%2FnR4TPT4m%2Flv5Q2zdazwQtehZdQFWrbhGVVp%2BdN60fnY0781lfhtfwEGZiXww9R4TOIjmSRFOvfC8gECyQwb7nghiqe%2FZ%2BSuUe52d2YS3J%2BYojoQ3Mf5QzOgcoV5l6deGuPk5b2JCWUO%2BCGx0YcgLJ5hfX%2Frz0%2F3%2FiGTc3Z7FFGuCgEW3U2xwU3y5TjAKJASGrp3U6RJzTljtaQRJjHqq2F0ShQ%2F88TaEyIGlFPM4%2FdoqJq1V8bqkhu%2FIry1CyBlfGexCvLxfO6NHKgKfzTu2wokFgGfAkRuxza3ZzCS50%2BjL%2Fqx66xLGfEsXu7X8d4L67OKBJjB32lo8EAuZ2amQ9bGe0MhagXjytIZ1RDdSWGTzfdC8RZqD3lbLxUQXmHMfRG%2Ba6HBYcUDARwu%2BIMd7cEIncivT5KTXBrtWoVa9Au3WmQX82uvIAwYSNkprU%2By4S0P%2F%2BaJfb359NWGgL36trqfVjsABpT4dWhtEsgK9fpau1PkFB%2FAq7nrDggZNZw23uOv4uQiUng5sxX6EErAJs65hb46EkCMgJ3M7YVPvYrTZctwyxKVPnmZVrP%2F2tc6pqgB9NqMkOzNL3xhyyNc4Dlnj9AjtLW0W2HY20MuEXDTZ5YbWtBvsdiXxvMxGKGs2aoOyGuFHTKADmvenUcWvM4YE%2FPETfWBBgbP3D0H%2FGpRf7Rz1ir09uAnmHfBRTzBjAwK77wnWeDP7vLPL2R0eeu8U6NYiO%2Bt8vso8vXpLfVhWW%2F7e70Y0GXCcCjbMdSyavHo%2FMxOqf%2FjTeQXE4yGHFa1lICncLuAarBPuARbUBygHeCXxsRH3RXoDsOzqVje5TprOWEoqw4CyqU6WWTNQy5lOOo%2FiizQl1YEuyLPgDVbVC8XdVzUhIeYVOeFEYIhh7tIOHyhm0mqJH%2FAeH1UxTWpHj0nDJtAVzSp3MOhHtBcX13m3vle8BBqNl5Y1csAUxXvGAJgMzsFT9zyaJlT0EmfT8qXlscSu4JNP2afhc4V9ISccPYBOZ4rYjK4GgeFCqK6Yhl36o%2FfRToGlGLAMoFpnAMob9R8A2iSAihKqxgCgQKW28UIa92xbYYaUB1SgGEclQdNtpSwndrfwyu8MYazTVUBjq%2BePDlo1XRFn0lTjw3CxdQqJn1pmVotGV02xdApcGaXdCLoKc4l4b%2F6jpJ9UYAaoXD1OwMdmhCX9NKOB4IyQmudXXqC30LR4fgUViYQde1taFr4Nb0F91BGjZNnssY6YkGL8GtOopLa3MmJVwlgrtAAOSmrfWR0xwO6WnXaZ6y6kQIt1xLrIuTpdYgRrEGJ9aEpKTDcuIQAaU0gMnBhUA1xlSTY815yjJ5xZvjrM%2BRQSq5S14XpxLHNNgdlBHTGxpjq%2FXaPdGfG5mq9Ht962Covfu9saDF0QfVjenTxjyKq9jhgDcsrio5TYq0xPjdH2UNLybM3%2FA%2BdW%2BYqz7gtt2pt1Dz5KX2E7lyWLwZOlrdJXYqp0X%2Ftq2L4YkHXGpPezdOWMsbXuAJN0I%2B2MsRV8ocmM1LIz1nGRlpMidG%2Fcj3U6f0pvWwe9pWtXvve7LYDFRb2L4ul9Rb1FUD80OXtjJLy9KDeU1RNgWG4tPL9FywESHQ7LZRVsxBz7Tg2gGvVw2q2HA3lbeuxeJLvNoP85PreSU4CthixyCbudY42Phpz5UijD5qJ8hI5JYHSqpd9f8FkT%2FHZTZQ7SQDS5xuuYM5dN9ueEuvy5M%2FFqfbXb1GlNPlVOVJmafGoHotpE3T7ppMCO9qvvbsVf7WxLHbJ1%2FIrAHJe5mrHr0QAcm5nD3IAP9i%2FRaNTN4HfOfVv50S0%2BUK%2F2OQH4CJGAzX5BS73fRu6EbG284QRiiIkSPMtVincTqRGqZdoMKSdNBHsNW8nJVQw8UyxmnPYSIjTeCj87f3IARiCfEFe5lLxehhduisrC9YWIyR1KgixD6AGlKVrKyY84l79EKLSPqubgUBNckSeFSXa%2FUbSAM4ujhdYlKXIHoWqZbIdTfvzp2d%2FD1Y6XF46305HUJjS1yvTKtGnIUI7DzaOkFdOtcpPHhGySIP9NDj8TvtzMsWgulGXiOr6CP20d%2BYrnPweu%2FxslTZDZkiGzYXdJZlhP5roU1LLRRVtdil2flSXYu3hkpbVskJ1qIJ5uhenj3MVoMGswJ%2F9EkMnsJ2%2FxF4Iq55%2FiVDMkRleyciKKZc2%2F1yjN1Og02enRC9wBmKvN4SI%2Bmu9NNqnt4%2FtH4R77p%2B3vlTADhVgnSDuSNxdF1gRtbzSAVYZJbyGEOo9UUGQcwNYCoTwwjXwZZ2ABItltLANLW%2B24avV7Xd8bVlRQsE%2B9ym6RL9pwUmBYVWYzmsLwJMOnn6IN0mgwAnPHYnLC4KnmDlA1qOjUWJpuUZUZWit8I%2BZ4PgJxvG7Y9GGUNW8gPFKYoRoDBrylBzBVb9i6DKZitlHoRhznk3Dpu8RM26Qxc0R1bqR16QggE6iMZzdlTXjp0oo2Znd%2Bu1o27Awq3WbVGnwC5tFaNuMETFMR52RUi%2F944RLqiqYJajI1ip3Cn2bigw%2BBd0d45SVI3QU5cONgRT7FXzoBGc5D%2BCASLRXl8cYIpcfc%2BXKS75GcXs%2BJn77hu4J0h4%2BKagh4JefW0H9Mq7DtFUWZ2VR5Qe4OEICV9fqwwISU9iehmgMhSXz2K%2FJ80uNf)

[image: Network draft]

Suggestion:

1. I would use a shared DB for the keycloak instances, but since there is no VPN it cant be done
2. keycloak to keycloak user federation ?
3. Use the other companies as idP and script a switch to the main keycloak?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend dedicated "local" Keycloak in each company (with configured user federation to Active Directory). And one "global" Keycloak instance, which will have configured `Identity Brokering` to all "local" Keycloak instances. "local" admins will have still full power to manage their users and customize login theme. Users will have to select identity provider from the "global" Keycloak login page or apps may use client-suggested identity provider with `kc_idp_hint` query parameter.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it out in a test installation !

Comment: can you please explain how the flow would look after adding the global keycloak instance? I assume, when user tries to access main website which is portal.companygroup.com then user will be redirected to global keycloak login page and will see 2 buttons to login with comp-A or Comp-B? Or they will see login form as well along with that 2 button? If login form is there then where user will be redirected after login using global keyclok server? Many thanks

Comment: what if some of that compagnies needs to support SSO across several domains ?